# Firefox Sync: any way to control what gets synced to my mobile device?

Tags: firefox, sync

With Firefox Sync, I can synchronize bookmarks between Firefox on my PC and my mobile devices. I have thousands of bookmarks however, most of which I don't need while on the go, and the volume of bookmarks brings my main mobile device (Nokia N900) to a painful, grinding halt while syncing (which is automatic).
I'd prefer very much to only synchronize "mobile bookmarks", which I can organize when at a desktop PC.

So my question is: is there any way to control what gets synced or to exclude certain items from the sync process?

**Edit**: Since it appears Firefox Sync doesn't offer such functionality, and Xmarks isn't supported by my device, I'll pretty much accept any answer that improves over manually copying bookmarks over. Even if the "synchronization" would require a USB cable.

Comment: [XMarks for Firefox](http://download.xmarks.com/download/firefox) + [Mobile XMarks](http://blog.xmarks.com/?cat=17).

Comment: @muntoo: The mobile version appears to no longer be maintained (I don't have an iOS device).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Firefox Wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Services/Sync/Xmarks#Features):

> - Sync currently does *not* support the following:
>
>   - Web access of your data - Since your data is encrypted on your computers, you cannot log on from any computer to access your data. You will need the Sync software to decrypt your data and display it to you.
>   - Home/Work Profile support - You will need to set up two separate Firefox Sync accounts.
>   - No Sync on quit - Your data will be synced when you restart your browser. You can also manually force a sync before you quit if you need immediate access to that data.

So, at least for now, the answer is "create separate accounts or use [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) until Firefox Sync is more feature complete.  (It *is* still in beta.)

Comment: I can't find any conclusive information that Xmarks works on the N900...

Comment: If all else fails, it has a mobile web interface at http://my.xmarks.com.  But my searching seems to say that Xmarks itself doesn't work.